# Reactjs : Passing array as prop to child function component. Modifying the array in child is causing state mutation exception

Tags: reactjs

Parent Component code:

```
const ParentPage = ({ }) => {

const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState([]);
```

Inside render:

```
              <ChildPage records={filteredResults}/>
```

ChildPage code:

```
const ChildPage= ({ records}) => {
  const [displayStore, setDisplayStores] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    if (records.length === 0 || records.length > max) {
      setDisplayStores([]);
      return;
    }

    records.forEach(record=> {
      if (record.total) {
        let hoverText = '';


        if (!record.sum) {
          hoverText += '- Missing sumData';
        }

        if (hoverText === '') {
          record.indicator = <DataIndicatorIcon status="good" />;
        } else {
          record.indicator = (
            <DataIndicatorIcon status="ok" hoverText={hoverText} />
          );
        }
      }

    });

    setDisplayStore(records);
  }, [records]);

  return (
    <ReactTable

      getTdProps={(state, row) => ({
        onClick: (event, cb) => {
          onRowSelected(row.original);
          cb();
        },
      })}
      data={displayStore}

  );
};
```

Error:

```
Error (Invariant Violation: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path....) is caused due to setting record.indicator
```

Assumed Problem:

```
          record.indicator = <DataIndicatorIcon status="good" />;
        } else {
          record.indicator = (
            <DataIndicatorIcon status="ok" hoverText={hoverText} />
          );
        }
      }
```

How can I update the props here without causing state mutation error

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array `updatedRecords` from `records` using `.map` instead of updating it in-place using `.forEach`.

```
const updatedRecords = records.map(record => {
  if (record.total) {
    let hoverText = '';


    if (!record.sum) {
      hoverText += '- Missing sumData';
    }

    if (hoverText === '') {
      record.indicator = <DataIndicatorIcon status="good" />;
    } else {
      record.indicator = (
        <DataIndicatorIcon status="ok" hoverText={hoverText} />
      );
    }
  }
  return record;
});

setDisplayStore(updatedRecords);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing an array, and arrays are passed by reference.if you don't want to change the state of the parent component, you need to pass a new array.
this could be one solution:

```
 <ChildPage records={[...filteredResults]}/>
```

Comment: Thanks meisam. I get the below error after making the change                                                          Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at trackProperties (trackForMutations.js:16)
    at trackProperties (trackForMutations.js:32)
    at trackProperties (trackForMutations.js:32)
    at trackProperties (trackForMutations.js:32)

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code in ChildPage which resolved the issue

const updatedRecords = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(records));